# Connecting the cathode of a diode to the output of a multiplexer

Tags: arduino-ide, led, esp32, multiplexer

From the image, the diodes share the same anode which is driven by 'Do Something'. My question is: through using Arduino IDE, what code should I write that connects the output of the multiplexer (Z) to a specific diode's cathode (Y0 or Y1 or ... or Y7), which in turn is connected to 'Do Something' that drives the cathode probably? In this code, I want the ESP32 microcontroller to connect this cathode to 'Do Something' for say 3 seconds and then switch to the next diode's cathode with a delay of 0.1 seconds [where no diodes' cathodes are connected to Z]       (and so on: in a continuous loop).

Here some code I found online but not sure what needs to be added to get the proper functionality:

```
int outputs[4] = {4,0,2}; // pins for selecting LED
int inhibit_pin = 15; // pin for turning off all LEDs


void setup() {
  for(int i;i<3;i++){
    pinMode(outputs[i],OUTPUT); // output selection for LED control
  }
  pinMode(inhibit_pin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(inhibit_pin,LOW); // raise high to disable all
 
}


void loop() {
  // looping through all 8 LEDs
  for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
    // turn on LEDs based on bit conversion
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      digitalWrite(outputs[i],bitRead(j,i));
    }
    delay(100); // delay .1 sec
  }
}
```

I don't think that "digitalWrite(outputs,bitRead(j,i));" is actually needed and I am not quite sure of what it does.

[image]

Comment: `bitRead(j,i)` reads the i-th bit from a bitstring. e.g The number 6 has the binary representation `110`. bitRead(6,2) reads a 1 as it starts from right bit0 = 0, bit1 = 1, bit2 = 1. In your program this code is written to the output pins which control the multiplexer to use Y6. That's all. The program should work as it is. BTW: You will only see an effect if the diodes in the schematic/picture are LEDs, and "Do Somethig" does something i.e provides a constant or fast pulsing voltage.

Comment: What is the MUX?

Comment: `for say 3 seconds and then switch to the next diode's cathode with a delay of 0.1 seconds` If you mean you want **none** of the eight outputs to be driven during the `0.1` second period, you should [update your question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/80871/edit) to clarify.  As is, that is not something your code is doing.

Comment: what kind of diodes are you using? ... why do you even need them?

Comment: My idea is to use the microcontroller for only controlling the MUX (each time, one Y0 is connected to Z). The 'Do something' Block continuously provides appropriate signals for driving the anode of a diode and Z (cathode of a diode). The diagram only shows a small part of my project, and the 'Do Something' is a very complicated system. It works nicely when one diode is connected directly [without the MUX] to 'Do Something', but now I want 8 diodes, each time one diode gets connected to 'Do Something'.

Comment: Why not use 1 diode on Z, and remove the 8 diodes between pins Y0...Y7 of your MUX and  your `Do Something` block? That would only allow current to flow one way between Yx and Z, using one diode instead of 8.

Comment: I rolled-back your latest edit because you deleted the URL for the image but left the image tag in and also the content of your question makes reference to this image.  If you have *good reason* to get of the image, and it's *not clear that you do*, remove both the tag and URL and references to it.

Comment: Your "do something" common anode input should probably have a pullup to avoid a floating condition.

Comment: You should edit your question and put the image back. Without it your description is going to be very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted should loop through the 8 possible MUX in/out pins (Y0...Y7) connecting one at a time to pin 3.

Assuming your Y0 through Y7 are each connected to a pin on your "do something" block, the mux should connect each of the 7 pins on your "do something" to Z.

One problem I see is that your code changes the pin select values on the MUX while the MUX is enabled. As you execute your `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)` loop and toggle the different select bits to S0...S2, the MUX will connect different Y0...Y7 pins to Z, until it settles on the final set of values for S0...S2. You should really set inhibit_pin to HIGH (disabling the mux before entering your `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)` loop, and then set it to LOW again at the end of the `i` loop and before the delay. (to re-enable the MUX at the now-completely-selected pin.)

Your description is a little hard to follow, but it sounds like that is what you want.

If you want each pin to be connected for 3 seconds, then not connected to any pin for .1 seconds before moving on to the next pin, you might rewrite your loop like this:

```
void loop() {
  // looping through all 8 LEDs
  for (int j=0;j<8;j++){

    // disable the mux while selecting a pin
    digitalWrite(inhibit_pin,HIGH); 

    // select a MUX pin
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      digitalWrite(outputs[i],bitRead(j,i));
    }
    // re-enable the mux now that we've selected a pin
    digitalWrite(inhibit_pin,LOW);
 
    delay(3000); // leave the pin active for 3 seconds.

    // disable the mux for .1 seconds
    digitalWrite(inhibit_pin,HIGH); 
    delay(100); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Out of curiosity, if I had two identical MUXs [same pins] and 16 diodes, then how would the code be changed to connect each of the 8 pins to Z of both MUXs at the same order/time [i.e. Y0 to Z of MUX1 and Y0 to Z of MUX2, then Y1 to Z of MUX1 and Y1 to Z of MUX2, and so on]? Excuse the wording of my question as I am trouble in putting my thoughts into words.

Comment: You could drive 2 MUXs with your Arduino, or better yet get a 16 channel MUX (altough with 1 16-channel MUX you could only select one channel at a time.) If you used 2 MUXs your tie their Z pins together, and use 3 different Arduino pins for the channel selector on each MUX. I'd write a channel-selecting function that took a MUX number as input (MUX 1 or MUX 2, say) and used that to look up the pin numbers to select and enable a channel for that MUX, and then my loop would call the function for each MUX in turn.

Comment: It looks like you need 4 unique pins for each MUX (3 channel select pins and an enable pin.) You could lower that to 3 unique pins and a shared enable pin if you wrote your code to disable both MUXs, do the channel selection, and then enable both at the same time.

Comment: I initially thought that since the two MUXs are to be operated in the same manner, then the code can be used as it is. But since I haven't used Arduino IDE much nor hardware programming in general, I wrote my initial comment to double check and as you said that I need a function to call each of the MUX. Yes, I agree that the two MUXs can share the enable signal, VCC, etc except for Y0-Y7 and Z.

Comment: if you are aware of any relevant web pages, please share them with me

Comment: If you always want MUX1 and MUX2 to connect their same pins at the same time, you could just split the Arduino outputs and drive both MUXes with the same 4 control pins.